# Can we have the option to recommend moving a post to se.bioinformatics?

Tags: feature-request, flagging

Occasionally we get posts which would be more suited to the bioinformatics.se. However, there isn't an option to suggest the post should be moved under the 'community specific' flag:

[image]

Can we get this added? It (I think) would avoid the occasional issue of a user suggesting the post is moved to se.bioinformatics and then the OP double posting the same question in both places.

Comment: And to SE Medical Sciences?

Comment: @BryanKrause — There was a notice about Bioinformatics graduating recently. Given that can we revisit this question? It seems to me we get a fair number of posts that are OK, but would be a much better fit on that site.

Comment: @tyersome SE remains hesitant to add migration paths. It can be an irritant for the target site when people migrate junk. Based on the comments I see on questions that could do better on Bioinformatics or Medical Sciences, many of those target questions are either A) Not fully off-topic here, so even though they might be "better" somewhere else they aren't supposed to be migrated, or B) Not up to the standards of the receiving site. My understanding is they only really add migration paths when there are multiple questions per day following that path. Best to just flag for moderators to review.

Comment: @BryanKrause — OK, I'll keep on doing that then — thanks for responding!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can raise a custom flag (flag for moderator attention).

Migration paths aren't allowed with beta sites and really haven't had much attention in a long time across all of SE, as far as I know.

https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/261200/401068

[As of 2020, is it possible to set up migration paths to beta sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/354124/401068)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - seems reasonable. I guess I'm just used to hammering posts posts on SO with 'belongs on stats.se'..

Comment: @user438383 Yeah, it's puzzled me for a long time as a user. There's quite a bit of angst around migration in general; in particular, the issue of junk getting migrated, and especially getting migrated to certain sites (Worldbuilding, for example, complains about this a lot). It's on SEs radar to work on alternative mechanisms but who knows when.